# react bootstrap - adding custom bsStyle property to button

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using react-bootstrap for my project and I am trying to add custom bsStyle property to the button component. If I use the default bootstrap classes according to the following link http://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#buttons the class name is rendered properly. However if i change the property to `bsStyle='facebook'` it renders btn-undefined

So in short, I am clueless where am I going wrong when I pass bsStyle property to the  group in react bootstrap.

This is my HTML looks like

```
<Button id="facebook-btn" bsStyle="facebook" bsSize="large" block>
</Button>
```

and if I change my code to

```
<Button id="facebook-btn" bsStyle="primary" bsSize="large" block>
</Button>
```

it works fine and the class is rendered properly.

This is the console html log

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Got it working with `styleMaps` by defining in my root component :

> With react-bootstrap 0.23.7

```
import {styleMaps} from 'react-bootstrap';

styleMaps.addStyle('facebook');
```

EDIT :

> Now with react-bootstrap 0.30.x

```
import {addStyle} from 'react-bootstrap/lib/utils/bootstrapUtils';
import Button     from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Button';

addStyle(Button, 'facebook'); // can add more params for more styles
```

EDIT 2 :

Official documentation link : [Custom Styles](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#custom-styles)

EDIT 3 :

When I migrated my setup from browserify to webpack2 it wasn't working with this syntax anymore, changing it to this worked though :

```
// import Button  from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Button'; // previous
import {Button}   from 'react-bootstrap';
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like available values for bsStyle are:

- primary
- success
- info
- warning
- link

So when it is trying find facebook style it's failing, therefore it is set to undefined.

Comment: Is there any way I can set custom bsStyle? Other option is to set the className manually for e.g className="btn-facebook", but then the default bsStyle is 'btn-default' which overrides the btn-facebook style.

Comment: Set the className and make your styles to load after bootstrap or set more weight, by being more specific than bootstrap style. Or use !important (not recommended).

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this pull request: https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/pull/496. I will be publishing a release with this change shortly.

Comment: yeah I created an issue on git for this and fix has been pushed to master branch this morning.